# How to get the number of articles, images and existed links from the website using java script?

Tags: javascript

How to get the number of exit links from the website
 using java script?

Comment: I don't know, would you be so kind and code this for me? Please read [ask] before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `getElementsByTagName`and the tag you are looking for here is an example:

```js
console.log('articles:', document.getElementsByTagName("article").length)
console.log('img:',document.getElementsByTagName("img").length)
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<img/>
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the answer for : How to get the number of exit links from the website using java script?